# How to fill in pdf forms?

Tags: pdf

I tried to fill in pdf form in Master PDF Editor, Ocular or LibreOffice. Each of them are useable to create new forms, but I can not find the possibility to fill in a downloaded, offficial form. Is it possible to use one of them or is there any other software for this aim?

Comment: I don't think its possible to make a pdf form fillable electronically if the form owner has not made it so.

Comment: There is a great program called xournal.  Not exactly what you want but I use it all the time to "fill in" government forms.  It allows you to annotate very easily.

Comment: Thank you, I've just installed Xournal and it looks fine. I can write on the surface wherever I will. Is there not any plugn to it wich makes the pdf fillable?